# Ноль в конце данных ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Суть проблемы, отправляю запрос по клику на ссылку:

```
$("#selectRegion > a").click( function() {

      var RegName = $(this).text();
      var RegID = $(this).attr("id");

    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        Name: RegName,
        ID: RegID
};

      $.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "text",
         url : "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
         data : data,
         success: function(respond){

alert(respond);

}
      });

   });
```

Обрабатываю, возвращаю обратно:

```
function my_action_callback (){
  header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf8');
  $RegName = $_POST['Name'];
  $ID = $_POST['ID'];
  $ssilka = '?cat='.$ID;

  $region = array("URL" => $ssilka, "NameOf" => $RegName );

echo $ID;

}
```

В итоге мне в алерте выводятся нужные мне данные с 0 в конце? Откуда здесь 0 и как его убрать?

Comment: а почему вы возвращаете то, что посылаете ? ($ID)

Comment: Это просто к примеру, в основном скрипте я json возвращаю, но и с обычным текстом та же проблема. Т.е даже если будет написано echo 'Ноль изыди!', я получу в алерте Ноль изыди!0

Comment: exit помог. Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю это происходит потому-что результат `my_action_callback()` распечатывается вордпресом, добавьте `exit` или вместо echo

```
return "Ноль изыди";
```